# Option highlight in HTML Multiselect

Tags: html, css, select, multi-select

I am using HTML Multi select with fixed width but when i am selecting any value which has longer text, the selection does not happens properly and text is not visible after scroll and its not even highlighted.

I have attached the JS Fiddle link for easy replication of the issue.

```
<table>
  <td>
    <select multiple="true" name="available" size="15" style="width:250px; overflow-x: auto">
      <option value="1">Test 1</option>
      <option value="2">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gn4kds0j/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to change style using pseudo selector:

> option:checked {
> width: fit-content
> }